# jQuery formatting a date range

Tags: jquery, html, mysql, date

I have a page that allows the user to select a date range and then creates a pdf report from a database having the date between the range selected. This was working fine until I realized I cannot use the `html` `input` type `date`. Only certain browsers support it. So I am using this jQuery: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range However, now the date format is all wrong. MySQL takes a date format of `yyyy-mm-dd` and this is sending it in as `mm/dd/yyyy`. I have tried changing the format like so and nothing changes. Any ideas?

```
 <body>
    <div class="dateselectwrap">
        <form action="reports/arrivals.php" method="post">
            <div class="dateselect">
                <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="start" id="from" required="yes" />
                <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="finish" id="to" required="yes" />
                <p >Format options:<br />
                  <select id="format">
                    <option value="yy-mm-dd">ISO 8601 - yy-mm-dd</option>
                  </select>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="datesubmit">
                <input type="Submit" name="Submit">
            </div>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
              <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
              <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
              <script>
              $(function() {
                $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
                $( "#format" ).change(function() {
                  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $( this ).val() );
                });
              });
              </script>
              <script>
              $(function() {
                $( "#from" ).datepicker({
                  defaultDate: "+1w",
                  changeMonth: true,
                  numberOfMonths: 3,
                  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                    $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
                  }
                });
                $( "#to" ).datepicker({
                  defaultDate: "+1w",
                  changeMonth: true,
                  numberOfMonths: 3,
                  onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                    $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
                  }
                });
              });
              </script>

        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `dateformat`, like : `dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'`

```
     <script>
          $(function() {
            $( "#from" ).datepicker({
              defaultDate: "+1w",
              dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',  
              changeMonth: true,
              numberOfMonths: 3,
              onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
              }
            });
            $( "#to" ).datepicker({
              defaultDate: "+1w",
              dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
              changeMonth: true,
              numberOfMonths: 3,
              onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
              }
            });
          });
          </script>
```

documentation available here:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Comment: It's actually `dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',` If not it makes it like `20132013--mm-dd`. Thanks a lot, though!

Answer (score 0):

The jQueryUI `Datepicker` widget has a `dateFormat` option you can use either when creating the widget or after the fact using the `.datepicker("option", "dateFormat", ...)` function.

There is an example [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats) and documentation is [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat).

Comment: Answers that just contain links are frowned upon, I believe. Put some details, and then link to them for more information, like rkp's answer.

Comment: Frowned upon by whom? I'm not sure simply providing code is inherently the best way to answer every question, and especially not, in my opinion, when it's a one line fix and the documentation is extremely straight-forward. Teaching people to use the documentation is important. Particularly in this case, where the asker has shown no more effort than copying and pasting code from examples together without understanding how the code works.

Comment: From http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers - _I think that links are fantastic, but they should never be the only piece of information in your answer._

Comment: Thanks for linking to that discussion. I understand the points made, and linkrot is especially valid which I had not considered, but I still disagree that links alone can never make a good answer. The analogy in that first post is flawed- this person isn't asking for directions to the next building, he or she is asking someone to *bring* him or her to that building! Considering the code provided by OP, which literally includes copy/pasted code from the example, I don't believe providing the code for the answer itself is helpful since it will lead to more copy pasting and less understanding.

Comment: Not going to have an ongoing discussion of this here. If you think it warrants further discussion, it belongs in meta.

Comment: No need for further discussion- I appreciate your message and will keep it in mind (note I don't just go around on SO linking in all of my answers). All I was doing was explaining my reasoning behind this particular answer.

Comment: You could at least say "Use the `dateFormat:` option, its documentation is here, an example is here". Readers should at least get the gist of the answer by just reading it. Don't forget, the intended readers of your answer are not just the OP, they're other people who find the question by searching in the future.